# Creating A3 documents that are A4 pages side-by-side

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm rather new to InDesign, and have been having a little bit of trouble with all the pages stuff.

I'm trying to create a document that, once printed, will be folded in half. The document itself is A3 size, but the content (on either side of the split) will be A4 size.

What's the best way about creating this? In InDesign should I create an A4 document, and use pages to try and get them to align? Should I use A3 in InDesign and just draw myself a guide of where the halfway point is?

The final product will be double-sided and folded, so there's a cover page, information in the middle and then more information on the back.

I apologise if my terminology is off or hard to follow, please feel free to correct anything or ask for clarification and many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to set the document up in A4 with "Facing Pages" set to true. You may want to set the starting page number to 2, so you do not have a separate page for the cover.

Comment: That has worked wonderfully, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A4 with spreads mode `On` should be a safer bet, also easier to print on normal office/home printers if anybody needs to print the docs.

Comment: I happened to have spreads on while I was trying to figure it out earlier, and it definitely gave me the result I was looking for. Thank you so much :)